the generators of isotropy subspace with two-dimensional fixed- point subspace of $D_4 \times S^1$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Generators of } \Sigma & \textbf{Fix}(\Sigma) \\ \hline
(z_x, z_y) \mapsto (z_x, -z_y) 
\\\quad \mapsto e^{i\pi}(-z_x, -z_y) & z_y = 0 \\ \hline
(z_x, z_y) \mapsto (z_y, z_x) \quad \\\mapsto e^{i\pi}(-z_x, -z_y) & z_x = z_y \\ \hline
(z_x, z_y) \mapsto e^{i\pi/2}(z_y, -z_x)\\ \quad \mapsto e^{i\pi}(-z_x, -z_y) & z_x = iz_y \\ \hline
(z_x, z_y) \mapsto e^{i\pi}(-z_x, -z_y) & \mathbb{C}^2 \\ \hline
\end{array}
I am reading this table of two-dimensional fixed- point subspace of $D_4 \times S^1$. In the first 3 rows, isn't the second operation just the identity operation? Why is it necessary, does it correspond to the $S^1$? And what does the second row mean anyways? Is it just short for listing the 2 operations seperately?
